# Finding the linear constraints in a domain

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If we take $f:S_1\to\mathbb R$ by $f(\vec x)=(x_1-2)^2-(x_2-1)^2$.

And Considering the domain $S_1=\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^2\ni0\le x_1\le1,|x_2|\le\frac{x_1}2\}$.

How do we write a series of linear constraints in  $S_1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint $$|x_2|\le x_1/2$$ is equivalent to $$\max(x_2,-x_2)\le x_1/2,$$ which is equivalent to the pair of constraints
\begin{align}
x_2 &\le x_1/2 \\
-x_2 &\le x_1/2
\end{align}